# Allowing users to specify regular expressions in SQL select statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2005, t-sql, select

I need your advice. I'm writing an ASP.NET web application and I'm considering whether or not to allow users to specify search words in the database using regular expressions.

Two questions:

1. Does SQL Server support using regular expressions for SELECT statements?
2. Is it safe to allow users to specify regexps for database selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1 - No, but you may use CLR function for this, like:

  ```
  public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
  {
      [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true)]
      public static SqlBoolean RegexMatch(string Pattern, string Expression)
      {
          return new Regex(Pattern).IsMatch(Expression);
      }
  };
  ```
- 2 - Safety **completely** depends on your realization